# Get host Name (C++)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Windows function call that get local hostname and IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933774/c-windows-function-call-that-get-local-hostname-and-ip-address)

I tried lot. How get host name in c++. I am using windows 7.
Please anyone help me.

I use

#include"unistd.h"

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far (specifically, the code you have). It's very difficult to help without more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
int main()
{
    char szPath[128] = "";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    gethostname(szPath, sizeof(szPath));
    printf("%s", szPath);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```