# C / C++ How to check domain name on current machine?

Tags: c++, c

I am looking for C or C++ solution to check domain name on current machine just like CGI and $ENV{'HTTP_HOST'} does it.

Thanks for any example, advice, resource I will appreciate all ;)

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `$ENV{'HTTP_HOST'}` isn't the current machine host or domain name. It's the value of the `Host` HTTP 1.1 header.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdomainname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, you may use `hostname` command.

On windows, the solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933774/c-windows-function-call-that-get-local-hostname-and-ip-address).

Comment: +1 but can you desribe how it recognize domain name ? What is a sample "hostname" returned from this ?

Comment: Take a look at the following references: 1. http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_named.htm             2. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-my-linux-machine-name/