# Win32 My IP adress with C programming

Tags: c, winapi, ip, named-pipes

I am doing some work for my school but I have this problem.
It is a win32 server.
How can I know, in run-time the IP address of the server ?
I don't use sockets, I use CreateNamedPipe().

Comment: I need to complete ("\\\\%s\\pipe\\duplex").

Comment: GetComputerNameEx seems to do the job. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx You can also use the winsock library to get the IP/server name even if you don't use sockets. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933774/c-windows-function-call-that-get-local-hostname-and-ip-address

Comment: Named Pipes do not use IP addresses. The server creates a named pipe using `"\\\\.\\pipe\\<pipename>"`, and the client connects to the pipe using `"\\\\<servername>\\pipe\\<pipename>"`, where `<servername>` is either the server's network machine name, or `.` for the local machine.

Comment: I must use something like "\\\\192.168.21.7\\pipe\\duplex" where 192.168.21.7 is the IP address of the computer where the server runs. The server and clients work on the same network.@Remy Lebleau.